# Mutual inclusion with singleton

Tags: c++, singleton, circular-reference

I currently have a problem with mutual inclusion in a project of mine (C++).

Normally, if I had a mutual inclusion problem, I'd easily solve it by either forward declaration or redesigning the classes a bit. But this time, I'm stuck:

I have a class called *Game*, which creates and launches core game systems, where one of these is called *GraphicsSystem*.
In the Game constructor, a GraphicsSystem object is dynamically created and stored in a GraphicsSystem* pointer. Looks like this:

```
Game::Game ()
{
    gfxSys = new GraphicsSystem(80, new Camera());
}
```

Now my GraphicsSystem class needs to access a Game class's method at one point to get the player object, which is stored within the Game object. The respective part looks like this (Game is btw a singleton!):

```
void GraphicsSystem::handleFrame ()
{
    ElementList elements = Game::instance()->getPlayer()->getEnvironment()->getElements();
}
```

Now I tried forward declaration in both directions already, but that wouldn't satisfy the compiler. I could of course also just put the player pointer into the graphics system, but I really don't want to do that, since he doesn't belong there.

Is there any way to resolve this without me having to change the design too much? I'm really stumped right now, so I hope you guys can help me.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 (Visual C++).

Thank you in advance!
Chris

Comment: Can you give some details about what happens when you tried forward declaration? Also what is the structure of your code files? I mean the relevant classes are in which files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward declare GraphicsSystem in Game.h.  Include Game.h in GraphicsSystem.h if it needs it.  Include Game.h and GraphicsSystem.h in Game.cpp.  Include Game.h and GraphicsSystem.h in GraphicsSystem.cpp.
That should work based off the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks, the fact that I now included GraphicsSystem.h directly in the Game.cpp fixed it. Usually, I never include another header file within the .cpp other than the corresponding class declaration file (meaning only a Game.h inclusion in Game.cpp). Should I only do the inclusion in .cpp when using forward declarations?

Comment: @Christoph if you have to use the non-matching class (the GraphicsSystem class in this case) in the implementation of the class, you need to include the header file, regardless of whether you use a forward declaration, but whe you do a forward declaration, you will almost always have to include the other header file.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to break circular dependencies in C++.

1) Create a 'interface' class which lists the methods implemented by your real class and which your real class inherits from. Then you can include that instead of the declaration of the real class.

2) Pimpl - a class holds an opaque pointer to its real data, solving the problem of having to include declarations for the types of member variables.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is going to sound dodgy, but have you considered holding a `global reference` to the initialized `Game` class?

I know globals are evil and so on and so forth, and I'm sure lots of people are going to rage, but *in my personal experience* I have succumb to **Singletonitis** with the `Game` class (among others) and found that sometimes it just simply isn't necessary.

The biggest question you need to ask yourself is ***"Who are you trying to protect your Game object from?*** and is there any reason why you need to ***request an instance each time*** you need the game class? I'm pretty sure that if your `Game` object wasn't initialized, you wouldn't be doing much else in your engine anyway.

Hope this might help you think about things in a different way, even though it's not answering your question directly.